# MSI B550-A Pro Motherboard Inquiry

Tags: motherboard, nvme

Can the MSI B550-A Pro Motherboard take a Samsung 980 Pro 4.0 NVMe M.2 SSD?

I have the motherboard and the NVMe drive in front of me, but do not see any ports/slots on the board where this SSD drive can fit.

Mine looks slightly different than the YouTube video....is it up under the black "tray" in this image? (the one with the two Phillips head screws on each end?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is of the first slot. Why can’t you use it? Try removing the heatsink per the instructions in the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound --- oh okay.  Can I put the nvme in the second slot or must it be in the first?  Removing the heatsink might be a bit more than I can get into...

Comment: You can’t unscrew a single screw? You have to screw down the device to install it regardless of which slot you used. You haven’t specified the reason you wanted to use the second slot instead of the first slot. Check your manual to determine which slot is disabled while using specific PCIe slots.

Comment: ohhh - okay - my screenshot is of the first slot - i missed that when I read thro things.  I'll see what I can do with that option :)

Comment: Are you looking at the black heat shield with writing on it? **That isn’t a fan.** if it’s that scary, the second slot, doesn’t appear to have a heat shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSI B550-A Pro supports NVMe M.2 SSDs

#### MSI B550-A Pro

- [Motherboard Manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/E7C56v2.1.pdf)
- [Support Site](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B550-A-PRO/support)
- [Marketing Site](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B550-A-PRO)
- Youtube: [MSI: How to install M.2 SSD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCTFABytrYA)

[image]

Comment: see my edit with an image....mine looks a bit differently to me, and I only really see one spot...or it could be my huge video card is covering the bottom slot :P

Comment: @DoctorFord - If your motherboard is actually different then you should [edit] your question to properly identify the motherboard model. It's either a MSI B550-A Pro or it isn't there isn't multiple variations of the MSI B550-A Pro.

Comment: @Ramhound - if you see from my image in my edit it is the MSI B550-A Pro - but I am nto seeing the two slots for nvme

Comment: @DoctorFord - You are making that determination with or without the GPU blocking the bottom slot? The second NVMe slot is below your GPU. Look on page 31 of the manual.